# Nonlinear fitting does not perform appropriately

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

I have a list as below one:

```
 mustbefitted={{0., 1.}, {4.4, 0.982211}, {8.9, 0.961575}, {13.3, 0.942571}, {17.8, 0.923857}, {22.2, 0.906203}, {25.1, 0.046994}};
```

I wish to fit the list with a function as `a - b t^c`

```
NonlinearModelFit[mustbefitted, a - b t^c, {a, b, c}, t];
```

But unfortunately the above fitting command does not perform correctly and I could not understand the mean of the massage after running the function i.e., `The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,c} = {1.,1.,1.}`!!!

Comment: For reference, the message is "The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,c} = {1.,1.,1.}." Please add this type of information to your questions in future!

Comment: Mind the capitalization `NonlinearModelFit` not `NonLinearModelFit`.

Comment: Most of the issues stem from the first point: `{0., 1.}`, which represents an indeterminate value in your fit function. It does not look like `a - b t^c` is a particularly good fit for this data either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took a look at your data,

```
ListLinePlot[mustbefitted]
```

[image: plot]

First I'd play with Manipulate to see if I can use the model I have and see if I can get anywhere close.

```
Manipulate[Plot[a - b t^c, {t, 0, 25.1}, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> Point[mustbefitted]], {a, 0.1, 5000000}, { b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 50}]
```

[image: doesnt look good]

It doesn't look good....the only values `b` and `c` that will give us that sharp drop off you have are quite high and `a` doesn't affect on it anymore.

But the data looks like an extremely linear piecewise function.

```
data = {{0, 1}, {4.4, 0.982211}, {8.9, 0.961575}, {13.3, 0.942571}, {17.8, 0.923857}, {22.2, 0.906203}}

lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
lm2 = LinearModelFit[{{22.2, 0.906203}, {25.1, 0.046994}}, x, x]
```

Have a look at the residuals...

```
ListPlot[lm["FitResiduals"], Filling -> Axis]
ListPlot[lm2["FitResiduals"], Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

[image]

Looks pretty good!...your data is awfully linear, except for the last data point compared to the rest.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{lm[x], x < 22.2}, {lm2[x], x >= 22.2}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 25.1}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[mustbefitted]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: v]

Not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but unless you can get a hand on more data points, or find a different model (the model you have doesn't seem to be the right one), there isn't much of a chance to get something better than this.

Comment: Thankx so much for your guide. Please let me check